# Guitar tabulature with HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create guitar tabulature with html/css.

I have this basic layout you can see here

**Style**

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family:sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
    height:100px;
    width:600px;
    margin: 70px auto;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    justify-content:space-between;
}


.string {
    height:1px;
    width:100%;
    background:black;
}
```

**Html**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="string"></div>
    <div class="string"></div>
    <div class="string"></div>
    <div class="string"></div>
    <div class="string"></div>
    <div class="string"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="string"></div>
    <div class="string"></div>
    <div class="string"></div>
    <div class="string"></div>
    <div class="string"></div>
    <div class="string"></div>
</div>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/jikol1906/pen/EByMZy?editors=1100)

I would like to be able to place notes (numbers) on the strings like

```
------0-
-----0--
----0---
---2----
--2-----
-0------
```

also chords like

```
-0------
-0------
-0------
-2------
-2------
-0------
```

What would be the easiest way to achieve this?

Comment: have you tried to put chords and arpeggios inside the markup as a regular monospaced text?

Comment: @fcalderan Just inside the div with "string" class? It does not look good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do this with less of code relying on transformation to adjust the position. Simply pay attention to the different value to have a perfect alignment:

```css
.wrapper {
  margin-top:30px;
  height: 96px; /* (16px)*6 */
  background:
    repeating-linear-gradient(
      to bottom,
      transparent 0 calc(100%/6 - 1px),#000 calc(100%/6 - 1px) calc(100%/6))
    0 -8px; /* (16px)/2 */
  position:relative;
}

.note {
  position:absolute;
  font-family:sans-serif;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  padding:0 4px;  /*4px will control distance between notes*/
  line-height:16px; /* Line-height not height!*/
  width:10px;
  background: #fff;
  transform:translate(calc(var(--x,0)*100%),calc(var(--y,0)*100%));
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="note">5</span>
  <span class="note" style="--x:0;--y:2">3</span>
  <span class="note" style="--x:1;--y:5">8</span>
  <span class="note" style="--x:2;--y:4">9</span>
  <span class="note" style="--x:3;--y:3">1</span>
  <span class="note" style="--x:4;--y:2">9</span>
  <span class="note" style="--x:5;--y:1">7</span>
  <span class="note" style="--x:7;--y:5">7</span>
  <span class="note" style="--x:2;--y:0">2</span>
</div>
```

You can make it more responsive using `em` unit:

```css
.wrapper {
  margin-top:30px;
  height: 6em; 
  background:
    repeating-linear-gradient(
      to bottom,
      transparent 0 calc(100%/6 - 1px),#000 calc(100%/6 - 1px) calc(100%/6))
    0 -0.5em; 
  position:relative;
}

.note {
  position:absolute;
  font-family:sans-serif;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  padding:0 0.2em;
  line-height:1em;
  width:0.5em;
  background: #fff;
  transform:translate(calc(var(--x,0)*100%),calc(var(--y,0)*100%));
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="note">5</span>
  <span class="note" style="--x:0;--y:2">3</span>
  <span class="note" style="--x:1;--y:5">8</span>
  <span class="note" style="--x:2;--y:4">9</span>
  <span class="note" style="--x:3;--y:3">1</span>
  <span class="note" style="--x:4;--y:2">9</span>
  <span class="note" style="--x:5;--y:1">7</span>
  <span class="note" style="--x:7;--y:5">7</span>
  <span class="note" style="--x:2;--y:0">2</span>
</div>

<div class="wrapper" style="font-size:30px">
  <span class="note">5</span>
  <span class="note" style="--x:0;--y:2">3</span>
  <span class="note" style="--x:1;--y:5">8</span>
  <span class="note" style="--x:2;--y:4">9</span>
  <span class="note" style="--x:3;--y:3">1</span>
  <span class="note" style="--x:4;--y:2">9</span>
  <span class="note" style="--x:5;--y:1">7</span>
  <span class="note" style="--x:7;--y:5">7</span>
  <span class="note" style="--x:2;--y:0">2</span>
</div>
```

In case you need better support for old browser you can get rid of `calc()` and CSS variables:

```css
.wrapper {
  margin-top:30px;
  height: 6em; 
  background:
    repeating-linear-gradient(
      to bottom,
      transparent 0 0.95em,#000 0.95em 1em)
    0 -0.5em; 
  position:relative;
}

.note {
  position:absolute;
  font-family:sans-serif;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  padding:0 0.2em;
  line-height:1em;
  width:0.5em;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="note">5</span>
  <span class="note" style="transform:translate(0,200%)">3</span>
  <span class="note" style="transform:translate(100%,500%)">8</span>
  <span class="note" style="transform:translate(200%,400%)">9</span>
  <span class="note" style="transform:translate(300%,300%)">1</span>
  <span class="note" style="transform:translate(400%,200%)">9</span>
  <span class="note" style="transform:translate(500%,100%)">7</span>
  <span class="note" style="transform:translate(700%,500%)">7</span>
  <span class="note" style="transform:translate(200%,0)">2</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with markup (spacer notes), or you could create CSS rules to indicate position along each line.

[Pen](https://codepen.io/isherwood/pen/agmzzV?editors=1100)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 30px auto 40px auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.string {
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
}

.note,
.spacer {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  line-height: 12px;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateY(-8px);
  margin-left: 15px;
}
.spacer {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="string">
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="note">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="string">
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="note">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="string">
    <class="string">
      <div class="spacer"></div>
      <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
      <div class="note">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="string">
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="note">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="string">
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="note">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="string">
    <div class="note">1</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

<sub>Yes, I *do* have seven fingers on each hand.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Although the correct answer has already been given, you could try another solution, that in my opinion, could be more scalable.
Using CSS variables and CSS grid, basically.

```css
:root {
  --noteA: 20%;
  --noteB: 40%;
  --noteC: 60%;
  --noteD: 80%;
  --order: '';
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 30px);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 100px);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  align-items: center;
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

.string {
  height: 50%;
  background-color: #8000805e;
  grid-column: span 6;
}

.note-a:after {
  content: var(--order);
  position: relative;
  left: var(--noteA);
}

.note-b:after {
  content: var(--order);
  position: relative;
  left: var(--noteB);
}

.note-c:after {
  content: var(--order);
  position: relative;
  left: var(--noteC);
}

.note-d:after {
  content: var(--order);
  position: relative;
  left: var(--noteD);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="string note-a" style="--order:'1'"></div>
  <div class="string note-b" style="--order:'2'"></div>
  <div class="string note-a" style="--order:'3'"></div>
  <div class="string note-c" style="--order:'4'"></div>
  <div class="string note-d" style="--order:'5'"></div>
  <div class="string note-c" style="--order:'6'"></div>
</div>
```

You can also take a look at this [pen](https://codepen.io/pedro-figueiredo/pen/gNwpLL).